# PDO MySQL Driver on Mac

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, driver

I have a mac with a custom PHP 5 install that built from about a year ago. I remember it took all Sunday and I had to compile about 20 times to get it right. The MySQL I have is from entropy and was precompiled.

Now I need to get PDO with the MySQL driver working and the driver is not installed. I tried the "pecl install pdo_mysql" and it dies at a point where it can't find some mysql files. Any ideas how I can fix this quickly?

```
checking for mysql_config... not found
configure: error: Cannot find MySQL header files under
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/PDO_MYSQL/configure' failed
```

I'll post whatever paths or messages you need to help me troubleshoot this. Will I have to compile PHP all over again, or can I just compile the pdo_mysql extension?

I hope I don't seem lazy, I just have a lot of code to write and not a lot of time to fight with my PHP configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're going to need to compile it by hand, instead of via PECL. You'll need to know where your MySQL install is. I don’t know about the Entropy packages, but the builds provided by MySQL (which I recommend) install into `/usr/local/mysql`.

```
$ pecl download pdo_mysql
$ tar xzf PDO_MYSQL-1.0.2.tgz
$ cd PDO_MYSQL-1.0.2
$ phpize
$ ./configure --with-pdo-mysql=/usr/local/mysql
$ make && sudo make install
```

And that should get you to the point where you can configure it.

Answer (score 0):

FYI; the MySQL PDO driver is included in the php 5.2.9 and 5.3 builds from Marc Liyanage's [entropy.ch](http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/php/)