# zlib directory with installation of PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, macos, pdo, zlib

I'm having trouble installing PHP's PDO_MySQL extension on a Mac OS X 10.5.8 server.  The problem comes from configuration.

I have tried taking the steps outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/384893/390977) but can only get so far as the command `$ ./configure --with-pdo-mysql=/usr/local/mysql`.  When I run this, I get the following error:

> configure: error: Try adding --with-zlib-dir=. Please check
>   config.log for more information.

I don't know what this means, and I can't seem to find much information on the Internet about it, other than "[zlib for Mac OS X: zlib is already included as part of Mac OS X](http://zlib.net/)" -- which to me means I don't have to install anything new.

However, I don't know where the zlib directory is that I should be putting here.  Does anyone know where I would find this directory?

**Edit**

[Pastebin of config.log](http://pastebin.com/10fyKaz2)

**Update 2**

After including `/usr` as the zlib-dir, I am getting the following error:

```
checking for mysql_query in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for mysql_query in -lmysqlclient... (cached) no
configure: error: PDO_MYSQL configure failed. Please check config.log for more information.
```

This was a little more dramatic in a different version (1.0.2):

```
checking for mysql_query in -lmysqlclient... no
configure: error: mysql_query missing!?
```

I've included the [config.log in a new Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/JzYvnqXF).

Comment: So what's in config.log?

Comment: @MarkAdler I've updated my question to give that information.

Comment: What do you get from these commands?
<br>
ls /usr/lib/libz*
<br>
ls /usr/include/z*

Comment: `$ls /usr/lib/libz*`
/usr/lib/libz.1.1.3.dylib /usr/lib/libz.1.2.3.dylib /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib  /usr/lib/libz.dylib  /usr/lib/libzfs.dylib

`$ls /usr/include/z*`
/usr/include/zconf.h /usr/include/zlib.h

Comment: Ian, did you ever find a solution for this? I'm running into what I think is the exact same issue: Mac OS X Server 10.5.8, trying to install pdo_mysql as a dynamic extension.

Comment: @StephenWashburn — Oh boy, it's been a while. I don't think I did. Looking at the code I wrote for this, I have two methods. It prefers PDO, but `if(!extension_loaded('pdo_mysql'))` I run a mysqli method. Not the most glamorous, but it abstracted things for when I could migrate things to a working server.

Comment: @IanHunter no problem, thanks for responding! I finally gave up and began the process of migrating to a newer server. I WAS running on an Xserve G5, the new machine is a mac mini which makes me a **little** uncomfortable even though I know they've been used as servers VERY effectively. But 16 GB of ram and a modern version of Apache and PHP makes it worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like zlib is already where it's supposed to be.  I don't know why configure isn't finding it.  The config.log does not provide enough information about how it tried to look for libz and failed.

I suppose you could try --with-zlib-dir=/usr, but that seems a little silly, since that's where it should be looking anyway.

Comment: It got me farther, but I'm not quite there yet.  It says mysql_query is missing?  (See my revisions.)

Comment: Then that's as far as I can get you.  I don't know what's supposed to be in mysql.