# How to install php extension on Macbook pro M1 chipset?

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-sanctum

I've a macbook pro with M1 chipset, I'm testing a Laravel web-app with Sanctum Api authentication.

First I send a GET requesto to `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` to get the cookies, then I send a POST request to the `/login` endpoint I get the following error:

`Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: select * from "users" where "email"`

I wonder what is the problem. Anyone can help me? Thank you for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

it's clear, "could not find driver".

you should try

```
brew install php-mysql
```

or you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745365/artisan-migrate-could-not-find-driver)

edit:

Apparently, this command is not working. I am not on macOS, sorry for that. But you should google "how to activate a php extension on macos" I think. you should activate mysql and PDO extensions.

- a solution is [this package](https://github.com/kabel/homebrew-php-ext)
- another solution is finding php.ini and uncomment mysql and pdo extensions.
- another solution is [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384809/pdo-mysql-driver-on-mac)

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the pdo_mysqli extension in the php.ini file. Remove ";" from the start of the line.

;extension=pdo_mysql

Comment: Thank you @SanjarRajabov
I did it but it doesn't work, unfortunately

Comment: Are you using the mysql db? If not enable extension of db which you use.